# How to convert ISO time inside DateTime to local time?

Tags: php, mysql, php-7

I create a DateTime object like this

```
$timestamp = new DateTime('2018-04-23T07:01:05.146000+00:00');
$timestampSql = $messageTimestamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I then insert the  $timestampSql into a timestamp field in my mysql table. But the problem is, that the mysql thinks that this time and date is in whatever timezone the mysql server is, and doesn't realize, that it is in fact originating from an  ISO time.

So basically, I need to somehow make sure the ->format outputs the timestamp converted to the current timezone the server is set to.

Comment: A good tip is to edit your question and include what timezone the server is in.

Comment: Well it is GMT +2, but that doesnt really matter since I want to use whatever timezone the server is set to be in.

Comment: So is the problem just that you don't actually know what timezone the server resides in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way you can easily switch a timezone using the dateTime Object:

```
function convertDate($dateTime){

$utc = 'UTC';
$newTimZone = 'TimeZone';

$newDateTime = new DateTime($dateTime, new DateTimeZone($utc));
$newDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($newTimZone));
return $newDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below function for server and user time zone

```
$time_diff = get_timezone_offset('America/New_York');

if(! function_exists('get_timezone_offset'))
{
   /*get time differ user and server */
   function get_timezone_offset($remote_tz, $origin_tz = null) {
      if($origin_tz === null) {
          if(!is_string($origin_tz = date_default_timezone_get())) {
              return false; // A UTC timestamp was returned -- bail out!
          }
      }
      $origin_dtz = new DateTimeZone($origin_tz);
      $remote_dtz = new DateTimeZone($remote_tz);
      $origin_dt = new DateTime("now", $origin_dtz);
      $remote_dt = new DateTime("now", $remote_dtz);
      $offset = $origin_dtz->getOffset($origin_dt) - $remote_dtz->getOffset($remote_dt);
      $offset =  $offset/60;
      return $offset;
  }
}


$current_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");

$new_date = $this->time_differction($current_date,$time_diff);

if(! function_exists('time_differction'))
{   
    /*Return new date and time as per user time zone */
    function time_differction($date_time, $time_diff){
        $time = strtotime($date_time);
        $time = $time - ($time_diff * 60 );
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
        return $date;
    }
}
```